# Difficulty writing a loop basing on user choice

Tags: c

I'm having difficulty writing a loop that will ask a user if he/she wants to continue the purchase of the products. It's part of my coursework at school. I have written all the required functions but Im struggling to get the loop to work.

Basically, what I want the loop to do is ask a user if he/she wants to continue the purchase and the answer should be either Y or N. Which will then take the remaining budget, implement it back to the program and run it again with that budget in mind, then deduct the value of the product chosen.

I have been trying to write that loop for more than 2 hours now and I'm running out of ideas.

That's the code I'm working with:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getItemPrice(char itemPrefix, int applePrice, int orangePrice, int pearPrice);
displayMenu(int applePrice, int orangePrice, int pearPrice);
withinBudget(int budget, char purchase, int applePrice, int orangePrice, int pearPrice);
purchaseItem(int budget, char purchase, int applePrice, int orangePrice, int pearPrice);

int main()
{
    
    int orangePrice, applePrice, pearPrice, budget; 
    char purchase;                                      
    printf("*****************\n");
    printf("Item prefixes\n");
    printf("A: Apple\n");
    printf("O: Orange\n");
    printf("P: Pear\n");
    printf("*****************\n\n");

    
    printf("***************\n");
    printf("*** MyStore ***\n");
    printf("***************\n\n");
    
    printf("**** SHOPKEEPER PANEL ****\n");

    printf("Welcome to the store. Please enter the prices for the following products: \n");
    printf("Please enter the price for the Orange: \x9C");
    scanf_s("%d", &orangePrice);
    printf("Please enter the price for the Apple: \x9C");
    scanf_s("%d", &applePrice); 
    printf("Please enter the price for the Pear: \x9C");
    scanf_s("%d", &pearPrice);  
    printf("\n\n");

    displayMenu(applePrice, orangePrice, pearPrice);
    
    printf("**** Customer menu ****\n");
    printf("Please enter your budget: \x9C");
    scanf_s("%d", &budget);
    printf("Please enter the item you would like to purchase using the item Prefix: ");
    scanf_s(" %c", &purchase, 1);
    printf("\n\n");

    displayMenu(applePrice, orangePrice, pearPrice);

    withinBudget(budget, purchase, applePrice, orangePrice, pearPrice);

    purchaseItem(budget, purchase, applePrice, orangePrice, pearPrice);

    return 0;
};

int getItemPrice(char itemPrefix, int applePrice, int orangePrice, int pearPrice)
{

    if (itemPrefix == 'A') {
        return applePrice; 
    }
    else if (itemPrefix == 'O') {
        return orangePrice; 
    }
    else if (itemPrefix == 'P') {
        return pearPrice;
    }
    else {
        return -1;  
    }

    return getItemPrice;
}

displayMenu(int applePrice, int orangePrice, int pearPrice)
{
    
    printf("**** Shop Menu ****\n");
    printf("Item:\t\tPrice\n");
    printf("A:\t\t\x9C%d\n", applePrice);   
    printf("O:\t\t\x9C%d\n", orangePrice);  
    printf("P:\t\t\x9C%d\n", pearPrice);    
    printf("\n\n");
    return 0;
}
withinBudget(int budget, char purchase, int applePrice, int orangePrice, int pearPrice)
{
    int getItemPrice(itemPrefix, applePrice, orangePrice, pearPrice);

    if (purchase == 'A') {
        return applePrice;
    }
    else if (purchase == 'O') {
        return orangePrice; 
    }
    else if (purchase == 'P') {
        return pearPrice;
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }
}
purchaseItem(int budget, char purchase, int applePrice, int orangePrice, int pearPrice)
{

    int items ;
    int calculation;

    if (purchase == 'A') {
        items = applePrice; 
    }
    else if (purchase == 'O') {
        items = orangePrice;
    }
    else if (purchase == 'P') {
        items = pearPrice;  
    }
    else {
        items = -1; 
    }

    if (items != -1) {
        calculation = budget - items;
        if (calculation >= 0) { 
            printf("Purchase was a success!\n");
            printf("Purchase details\n");
            printf("----------------------\n");
            printf("Item: %c\n", purchase);
            printf("Price: \x9C%d\n", items);
            printf("Remaining budget: \x9C%d\n\n", calculation);
            printf("Thanks for shopping with us!");
        }
        else {  
            items = -1;
        }
    }
    if (items == -1) {  
        printf("Purchase FAILED!\n");
        printf("Low budget or invalid item!\n\n");
        printf("Thanks for shopping with us!");
    }
;
```

I have already tried writing the while loop in the body of the program as well as inside of the purchase item function. I'm completely clueless at this point and don't really know what can I do to make it work. Or what I'm not doing that would help me this program to work as I  want it to.

Any help would be appreciated. As well as any tips on what can I do to improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a loop logic like this:

```
int main(void){
    ... // Your definitons
    bool proceed = true;

    while(proceed){
        ... // All your code here

        bool isValid = false; // Check the answer character's validity
        while(!isValid){
            printf("Would you like to purchase anything else? [Y / N]");
            char answer = getchar();
            putchar('\n'); // Add a line feed
            if (answer == 'Y' || answer == 'y'){
                proceed = true;
                isValid = true;
            }
            else if (answer == 'N' || answer == 'n'){
                proceed = false;
                isValid = true;
            }
            else{
                // Entered an unexpected character, force the user to enter a valid character
                printf("Please enter a valid answer\n");
                isValid = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have tried implementing that code I have run into some issues that I have managed to figure out myself. However, the only one that I can't seem to figure out that in C it keeps saying that I'm defining an illegal continue and it keeps giving me warnings in regard to continue itself. @Kozmotronik

Comment: How silly of me! continue is a C keyword, the errors is for this. I will edit the code, you replace continue keyword with something else other than C keywords.

Comment: So I have managed to get it working without having the information popping out prematurely, it was showing me the "please enter valid answer" information after have made 1st purchase. Managed to fix it but now the remaining budget from the 1st purchase doesn't carry over to the loop. Is there something wrong with my functions? or is there more information needed within the loop?

Comment: All the code that I have put in the question. Is the code that I'm actually using.

Comment: @adek I don't see your code in the question implemented with my suggestion. Did you implement my suggestion in your code? Your code won't iterate because there are no loops in your code. Now please provide us an updated information; Did you implement my suggested loop structure in your code?

Comment: I have managed to figure out the problem with the loop. I have not implemented the functions incorrectly, within the loop. This has now been fixed and necessary changes were done. The issue was that I did not set the budget to a purchaseItem function.